# Shift-arrow not working in emacs within tmux

Tags: emacs, tmux

I recently started using tmux (was a screen user before) and I'm loving it, except for one small problem. I use emacs within my tmux session and I am used to using Shift-arrow keys to move between emacs windows (not tmux windows). When running within tmux, these bindings seem to stop working entirely (it's like they don't register to emacs at all). If I exit tmux and just run emacs in my shell, they work fine.

I'm using iTerm2, ssh'd into a Linux box, running tmux/emacs there. I have the Shift-arrow key bindings set up as follows in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key "\M-[1;2A" 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key "\M-[1;2B" 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key "\M-[1;2C" 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key "\M-[1;2D" 'windmove-left)
```

When not running in tmux, I can confirm those are the right character sequences for the shift-arrow key combinations by doing C-q in emacs and then pressing the key sequence. Within tmux, even that doesn't work because it doesn't seem to see any input from the shift-arrow keypress (it just sits at the C-q prompt).

Looking at the key bindings for tmux, I don't think anything is bound to Shift-arrow keys and even if it was, they would only register after entering the prefix (which is bound to C-o in my case).

Any idea on how to make the shift-arrow keys work again within tmux?

Comment: I actually found the answer this myself but StackExchange won't let me officially answer my own question for another 7 hours as I don't have enough reputation yet. Anyway if anyone is interested, doing

    set-window-option xterm-keys on 

seems to fix it. I set this as a global option by putting this in my .tmux.conf and I seem to be back in business:

    set-window-option -g xterm-keys on

Comment: Try to vote to close question if you really can't

Answer (score 15):

First, make sure your TERM is correct at each location:

- `xterm`-something (e.g. `xterm-256color`) inside your local shell running in your *iTerm2* window
- `xterm`-something inside your shell after SSHing to the Linux system
  This should be the same as whatever you are using locally in *iTerm2*, since SSH should be passing it along to the remote side (and, importantly, the remote side should not be blindly overriding the value in a shell initialization file).
- `screen`-something (e.g. `screen-256color`) inside your shell running under *tmux* on the Linux system
  You should always use a `screen`-based TERM inside *tmux*.

Having an `xterm` TERM immediately outside *tmux* will allow *tmux* to recognize the modified arrow keys, but it will not pass them through unless you also have its `xterm-keys` window option turned on. Put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` on the Linux system:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

The sequences for the shifted keys should now make it through to *Emacs*, running inside *tmux*, across an SSH connection, inside an *iTerm2* window.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to use textadept in tmux.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I'm on Fedora-23 using a gnome-terminal. My TERM's and .tmux.conf are set as described in the answer. Setting the bindings as described in the question does work however. I'd really like to solve this mystery since it's also mucking up a ncurses app I'm working on.

Comment: @gogators same here; the above solution does not work for me even though I had exactly what was suggested.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift does not work, Ctrl+<f#> does not work and so on. Ctrl+d does work though.

Comment: In practice this means: `export XTERM=xterm-256color` (I am writing this becasue I did not know what "your TERM" in the answer means, I was looking for a comment explaining that... there was none, and now there is one.)

Comment: this solution don't work if the `TERM` in tmux is not `xterm` (e.g. Shift+F6 in `mc` doing F15 when `TERM=screen-256color`...)

Comment: I was about to chime in with "This solution did not work for me." but I found that simply starting a new tmux session was insufficient, but rather I had to quit all current tmux sessions and start a new one for the updated ~/.tmux.conf to take hold.

Answer (score 6):

First you must enable `xterm-keys` in your tmux config. So put the following in `~/.tmux.conf`

```
setw -g xterm-keys on
```

But, this will break other key combinations. To fix them, put the following in your`~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` config

```
;; handle tmux's xterm-keys
;; put the following line in your ~/.tmux.conf:
;;   setw -g xterm-keys on
(if (getenv "TMUX")
    (progn
      (let ((x 2) (tkey ""))
    (while (<= x 8)
      ;; shift
      (if (= x 2)
          (setq tkey "S-"))
      ;; alt
      (if (= x 3)
          (setq tkey "M-"))
      ;; alt + shift
      (if (= x 4)
          (setq tkey "M-S-"))
      ;; ctrl
      (if (= x 5)
          (setq tkey "C-"))
      ;; ctrl + shift
      (if (= x 6)
          (setq tkey "C-S-"))
      ;; ctrl + alt
      (if (= x 7)
          (setq tkey "C-M-"))
      ;; ctrl + alt + shift
      (if (= x 8)
          (setq tkey "C-M-S-"))

      ;; arrows
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d A" x)) (kbd (format "%s<up>" tkey)))
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d B" x)) (kbd (format "%s<down>" tkey)))
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d C" x)) (kbd (format "%s<right>" tkey)))
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d D" x)) (kbd (format "%s<left>" tkey)))
      ;; home
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d H" x)) (kbd (format "%s<home>" tkey)))
      ;; end
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d F" x)) (kbd (format "%s<end>" tkey)))
      ;; page up
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 5 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<prior>" tkey)))
      ;; page down
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 6 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<next>" tkey)))
      ;; insert
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 2 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<delete>" tkey)))
      ;; delete
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 3 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<delete>" tkey)))
      ;; f1
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d P" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f1>" tkey)))
      ;; f2
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d Q" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f2>" tkey)))
      ;; f3
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d R" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f3>" tkey)))
      ;; f4
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 1 ; %d S" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f4>" tkey)))
      ;; f5
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 15 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f5>" tkey)))
      ;; f6
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 17 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f6>" tkey)))
      ;; f7
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 18 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f7>" tkey)))
      ;; f8
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 19 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f8>" tkey)))
      ;; f9
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 20 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f9>" tkey)))
      ;; f10
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 21 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f10>" tkey)))
      ;; f11
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 23 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f11>" tkey)))
      ;; f12
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 24 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f12>" tkey)))
      ;; f13
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 25 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f13>" tkey)))
      ;; f14
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 26 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f14>" tkey)))
      ;; f15
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 28 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f15>" tkey)))
      ;; f16
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 29 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f16>" tkey)))
      ;; f17
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 31 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f17>" tkey)))
      ;; f18
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 32 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f18>" tkey)))
      ;; f19
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 33 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f19>" tkey)))
      ;; f20
      (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (format "M-[ 34 ; %d ~" x)) (kbd (format "%s<f20>" tkey)))

      (setq x (+ x 1))
      ))
    )
  )
```

Also I have my solution in [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Emacs#Shift_.2B_Arrow_keys_not_working_in_emacs_within_tmux)

Comment: comment left by @JeffKlukas: "oblique's answer is just what I needed to get this working through PuTTY on Windows as well (I don't have the reputation to add this as a comment, so making an answer instead).

When I turned on the xterm-keys option in tmux, Shift-arrow would produce text like 2C in emacs. By adding the above elisp code to my init.el, I get the expected functionality (especially useful in org mode)."

Answer (score 2):

tmux FAQ [used to contain the following entry](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/fe6f520054cc324911505a6c370a7b5cbe2f6d23):

> ## How do I make ctrl and shift arrow keys work in emacs?
>
> The `terminal-init-screen` function in `term/screen.el` is called for new frames, but it doesn't configure any function keys.
>
> If the tmux `xterm-keys` option is on, it is enough to define the same keys as xterm. Add the following to `init.el` or `.emacs` to do this:
>
> ```
> (defadvice terminal-init-screen
>   ;; The advice is named `tmux', and is run before `terminal-init-screen' runs.
>   (before tmux activate)
>   ;; Docstring.  This describes the advice and is made available inside emacs;
>   ;; for example when doing C-h f terminal-init-screen RET
>   "Apply xterm keymap, allowing use of keys passed through tmux."
>   ;; This is the elisp code that is run before `terminal-init-screen'.
>   (if (getenv "TMUX")
>     (let ((map (copy-keymap xterm-function-map)))
>     (set-keymap-parent map (keymap-parent input-decode-map))
>     (set-keymap-parent input-decode-map map))))
> ```
>
> And ensure `.tmux.conf` contains "`set -g xterm-keys on`".
>
> Alternatively, the `screen.el` file can be copied to the load path and
>   customized.

I opened tmux [issue #1349](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1349) to request restore for the FAQ entry.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, problems like this happen because of mistmatch between what the terminal emulator sends and what the client application expects.

Different terminal emulators have different degree of customizability, so familiarizing oneself with emulation tunables of a particular one is necessary.

Client applications depend on value of `$TERM` which is used to lookup terminal (emulator)'s capabilities in the `terminfo` (or `termcap`) database.

In your case, your emacs bindings use explicit sequences thus `$TERM` and terminfo are irrelevant: a specific terminal emulator is expected - as you already figured out, a `xterm`-compatible one.

Comment: See [Fix Terminals - Please](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/) for a proposal to standardize some of these differences/deficiencies in terminal input.  It's been [raised on iterm2-discuss](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.iterm2.general/119) but I don't think anybody's implemented it yet.